# angularfire2 + angular 4: fetching data and using it in a component

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

Alright, I recently switched form angularJS to angular 4.x and I am having some issues. Note that I am not moving any app, I am just building a new one from scratch, using Firebase as my back-end.

I got to the stage where I have authentication working fine (register and login). However, the built-in user system of Firebase allows for registration with email address and password - while I would like to add a username. The requirement is for this username to be unique.

As a structure, I have an auth.service which takes care of talking to firebase to register / login / logout. 
Conceptually speaking, my idea was as soon as a user wants to sign up (so, fills the form and click on the button), query the database for any user already registered with that name.
Which is what I have been unsuccessfully trying to achieve. i query the data, but when I want to use it, it always comes as undefined...

To simplify, what would be the best way to ensure a user can register only if the username he chose is unique?

I would appreciate any help, even if it is just to point out a tutorial, I find the documentation to be very hard to follow. I am using firebase 3.9 with angularfire2 v4.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two approach to check if the user is already registered.

1. **Firebase will throw an error if there's an already registered user**

Probably the easiest way and you don't need to add much code to your existing code. Just modify you observable error handling in your service where you implement the sign-up.

2. **Add "/users" node**

Before you execute your sign-up functionality, check your users list if there is an existing email something like this

```
db.list('/users', ref => ref.equalTo(signUpEmail))
```

Note that whenever you have a new registered user, add them to this list.

More info:

Query list - https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md

Comment: Hi brijmcq,
I will obviously accept your answer as I went down the path of the second solution.
A bit more tweaking and I actually show in realtime if the username is already taken.
Just need to tweak a bit more because currently I query the DB on each keystroke which is probably not ideal.

Comment: Personally, I prefer the 2nd solution but I always implement the 1st solution cause it is quick and easy and I would just get the error message and display it by using toast notification. I think what you need is to implement the `debounceTime` so not to query the db every keypress, and only query the db if the user stops typing after a few milliseconds.